# How to telnet into a transparent bridged modem through router

Tags: openwrt, telnet, bridge-router

So first off I guess what I want to do is be able to telnet into a transparent bridged modem to restart it. (The modem is a Actiontec c1100t) My router is a Linksys wrt1200AC running LEDE openwrt. If telnet is impossible is there a different way to reboot the modem remotely without having to go to the physical modem while in this mode? I'm not very experienced in networking so I'm sorry if I don't understand anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the modem normally have "static routing" configuration when you're able to connect to it? Also, what IP address does it have assigned while in bridge mode?

Comment: Not sure if its static but its a modem router combo. It did have a field in the options for static routing. While in bridge mode I cannot connect to it nor see it on the network. I can connect to the linksys by going to 192.168.0.1